# CMake/CPack: add_custom_command TARGET package POST_BUILD

Tags: cmake, package, cpack, post-build, cmake-custom-command

Having the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796670/cpack-deb-generator-control-file-has-bad-permissions-mdsums-0644-0644) described, I want to execute a shell script as a POST_BUILD command of TARGET "package". Target platform is Debian/Ubuntu.

I add following to the end of my CMakeLists:

```
 add_custom_command(
     TARGET package
     POST_BUILD
     COMMAND bash ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/fixup_deb.sh
     WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} 
     COMMENT "Fix file-permissions of md5sum files in debian package"
 )
```

But this does not work. When I call "make package" the script doesn't change.

At the moment I have a workaround with a custom target:

```
 add_custom_target(
     correctDeb        
     COMMAND bash ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/fixup_deb.sh
     WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} 
 )
```

But it would be much more comfortable and more fail-safe for me if this would be automagically done when calling "make package".

By the way, generation of *${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/fixup_deb.sh* works also well with:

```
 configure_file( "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/debian/fixup_deb.sh.in" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/fixup_deb.sh" @ONLY IMMEDIATE )
```

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem. Did you find a good solution for this?